# Installing server (on Windows) and client tools (on Windows, Linux and Apple) for version control

Tags: windows, linux, macos, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I installed and configured a Visual SVN server on Windows Server 2008.  I was also able to install Tortoise SVN on Windows as my client tool.  I'd like to get a client tool similar to Tortoise SVN for Linux and Apple operating systems.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/

**Few questions related to these installs...**

(1) What is the recommended protocol for a repository, and what are the differences between them (ie: https, svn, etc..)?

(2) Do Linux or Apple operating systems require a specific protocol?

(3) What are the recommended Linux and Apple client SVN tools to connect to my Visual SVN Server?  Right now, I only have Tortoise SVN configured on Windows as my client tool for checking in/out source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux, try http://rabbitvcs.org.

For MacOS, XCode should support SVN.  Check out this link, too:  http://alternativeto.net/software/tortoisesvn/?platform=mac

Assuming you're developing, too, the Eclipse SVN plugin is a Pop Favorite on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

1. VisualSVN Server supports only HTTP(S) access. HTTPS is recommended since it's secure.
2. No.

Comment: +1 .... thanks for the info!  Do you know what server is installed when the protocol is "svn://"?  I hope port 443 doesn't interfere with a web site (with a certificate) on the same server.  That's all I am worried about when using 443.

Comment: "svn://" protocol is provided by an independent server process called "svnserve" that uses a custom protocol over TCP/IP. It could be some custom-built Subversion server.

BTW you can use 8443 for VisualSVN Server in case 443 is already used by a web server.